# Am I doing things properly on this validation function?

Tags: javascript, css, validation, css-transitions, addeventlistener

I would like to know if this email validation function is properly made, or it could be done differently. Also i would like to know how can I delete error content without breaking the transition, I try with `innerHTML = ""` but the transition stop working. Thanks in advance.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    error = document.querySelector('.error'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    error.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    if (inputEmail.value !== "") {
      error.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      error.classList.add("show")
    } else {
      error.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks ok to me, with a few of points:

1. The `input` or `change` events are more appropriate for listening to input. Use `input` if you want to react to every change of input e.g. keystrokes, or selecting an email from a list of the browser's saved email addresses. Use `change`  if you only want the handler to run when the user has committed the change, e.g. through loss of field focus.
2. To animate the error element on hide, you need to listen to the `transitionend` event, and only remove the content after this has fired. This gives the animation time to complete. Otherwise, the box will just collapse immediately and there's nothing to animate.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('input', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    error = document.querySelector('.error'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    error.classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    if (inputEmail.value !== "") {
      error.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      error.classList.add("show")
    } else {
      error.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        error.innerHTML = '';
      }, {
        once: true
      });
      error.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.error.show {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm very grateful to you Richard. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Delighted to be able to help.